# Как при помощи метода sort сортировать массив по типам данных сначала цифры, потом null, строки

Tags: javascript, сортировка

```
var data = [1, 'firstString', 30, 500, true, true, null, 'abc', 
false, {test: 'Object'}, undefined],
    result;

result = prioritySort(data, ['number', 'null', 'string', 'object', 
'undefined', 'boolean']);
//expected result [1, 30, 500, null, 'abc', 'firstString', {test: 
'Object'}, undefined, true, true, false]

console.log('result', result);

function prioritySort(array, dataPriority) {
    return array.sort(function (left, right) {
        // write code here
    });
}

function isNull(value) {
    // write code here
}
```

Comment: *сначала цифры, потом null, строки* А true/false да всякоразные объекты - вообще выбросить, что ли? И эта... язык-то укажите (ну то есть видно, что это не то javascript, не то jscript, но всё одно - надо).

Comment: Это javascript) ['number', 'null', 'string', 'object', 
'undefined', 'boolean'])нужно в такой последовательности.

Comment: Ну так и рисуй функцию сравнения. Сначала определяешь тип операндов и сравниваешь по нему (обычный typeof, плюс отдельная проверка на null). Если тип одинаков - сравниваешь по содержимому (буде надо и вообще возможно, конечно).

Comment: Можно пример пожалуйста?